# Upload public files AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, swisscomdev

My application has an entity (let's say a blog post) and each post can have multiple files attached and an image. Every user should be able to see / download those files / images.

How can I get a public url to those files. I'm asking because I figured that uploading files with ACL "public-read" is not allowed in Swisscom Cloud and I also can't change the bucket privacy to allow reading files for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Before you upload any files or folders into a S3 bucket, you need to write permissions for the bucket.  Whenever you upload a file in Amazon S3, it is stored as an object and those objects consist of data that describes them. There are several ways to upload files, both with the management console and by [cloud syncing](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/synchronizing-data-to-s3-cloud-sync). Below are the steps to use the console to upload the files either by drag and drop or by simply pointing and clicking.

Uploading the files by drag and drop:

If you are using Chrome or Firefox, choose the files and folders and then drag and drop it into the destination bucket. To drag and drop files into a S3 bucket:

- Sign into the AWS management console, https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/
- In the bucket list, choose the name of bucket in which you want to upload your files and folders.
- Now, drag and drop your selection into the console window that has the objects in the destination bucket. The chosen files are now in the upload dialog box.
- In the Upload dialog box, drag and drop more files into the console window. To add more files, you can choose “*Add More Files*.” But remember that this option works only for files, not folders.

Uploading the files by pointing and clicking:

- Follow the same first two steps as that in Drag and Drop. After these steps, select the option to **Upload**.
- In the upload dialog box, select **Add Files** and choose one or more files to upload.
- Once the files are listed, follow one of the below steps-

  - To add more files, choose **Add More Files**.
  - To upload, click on **Upload**.
  - To set the permissions, choose **Next**.